# php compare multidimensional array equal

Tags: php

Array 1

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [prid] => 110
                [size_id] => 24
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [prid] => 117
                [size_id] => 24
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [prid] => 174
                [size_id] => 24
            )

    )
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 174
            [size_id] => 24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 174
            [size_id] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [prid] => 163
            [size_id] => 24
        )


)
```

I have 2 multidimensional arrays. I want to compare both arrays and resultant arrays are equal in both. 
(i.e) The answer is

```
[prid] => 174
[size_id] => 24
```

***Note:-*** i am using `array_intersect_assoc()`,but not working

How can we retrieve this???

Please tell the answer to this

Comment: i am using  array_intersect_assoc. but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach()` and `array_column()` to compare second array value with first array

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($array2 as $arr){

 if(in_array($arr['prid'],array_column($array1,'prid')) && in_array($arr['size_id'],array_column($array1,'size_id'))){
   $final_array[$arr['prid']] = $arr;
  }
}
$final_array = array_values($final_array);

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/979112

***Another easier solution using `array_intersect()` and `array_column()`***

```
$final_array = [];
$common_array = array_intersect (array_column($array1,'prid'),array_column($array2,'prid'));

foreach($common_array as $key=>$val){
  $final_array[] = $array1[$key];
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/979135

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $value1){
    foreach($array2 as $value2){        
        if($value1['prid'] == $value2['prid'] && $value1['size_id'] == $value2['size_id']){
            $new_array[] = $value1;
        }
    }
}
echo print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by using couple of array function and a foreach loop.
Try like this:-

```
$array1=[
    ['prid'=>110,'size_id'=>24],
    ['prid'=>117,'size_id'=>24],
    ['prid'=>174,'size_id'=>24],
];
$array2=[
    ['prid'=>174,'size_id'=>24],
    ['prid'=>174,'size_id'=>25],
    ['prid'=>163,'size_id'=>24]
];

$prid = array_intersect(array_column($array1,'prid'),array_column($array2,'prid'));
$size_id = array_intersect(array_column($array1,'size_id'),array_column($array2,'size_id'));
$array3 = array_merge($array1,$array2);
$result=[];
foreach ($array3 as $data){
    if(in_array($data['prid'],$prid) && in_array($data['size_id'],$size_id)){
        $result = $data;
        break;
    }
}
```

or like this

```
$result=[];
foreach ($array1 as $data1){
    foreach ($array2 as $data2){
        if($data1['prid']==$data2['prid'] && $data1['size_id']==$data2['size_id']){
            $result = $data1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It will give o/p like this [image]